# Write my own packet monitor

Tags: java, port, packet-capture

I am using an application called Splunk, which has 2 layers of data processing on separate systems. I can connect to both systems via putty and directly logging into the GUI.

[Archiecture of the system attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSuCI.png)

I want to monitor the output port on layer 1, and input port on layer 2 and find out the below information,

i. Raw data sent out of layer 1

ii. Raw data received into layer 2.

The two layers communicate using tcp.

I do not want to use an existing packet monitors/packet capture like tcpdump or winshark as I want to heavily customize the monitor to display various information. I want to write my own packet monitor in java

**I want to know**,

1. If layer 2 is listening to layer 1, can my program connect to the same port and print the raw text being sent? - the protocol is TCP
2. Is (1) possible for other protocols like udp, http and ftp?

(EDIT: Architecture attached

Info on the systems in case it is relevant,

1. system 1 is VMWare(Linux Ubuntu 4.4.10) running on a Windows machine.
2. System 2 is mac os.

Both systems have different IP addresses. I am connecting to both systems from the windows machine where vmware is running.
The two systems connect to the same wifi.
)

Answer (score 0):

There are some packet capture libraries written in Java, [jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/), [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/), and [Pcap4J](https://www.pcap4j.org/).
Both #1 and #2 are possible by these libraries, I think.

If you would pick Pcap4J I can help you. It's my library.

Comment: Thankyou very much. Let me start exploring on my own, I will get in touch with you once I hit a roadblock.